# How can you give someone access to set permissions without making them a project owner on Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-iam

We're trying to give a google cloud platform user account permission to change its own permissions and the permissions/roles of service accounts that it creates. Currently, the user account only has the default editor permission for the project it exists on. Essentially, we want to give it every permission that the owner account has except for viewing or modifying billing information. Is this possible?

We have looked at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tSnzoW4RlaQ) but there doesn't exist a role selection dropdown on service accounts anymore. When trying to edit the service account permissions to try and give it the `roles/storage.admin` permission, I get this notification:

[image]

The project owner has also tried to add the storage admin role to the service account, but roles don't show as they do in the video. All that is shown on his screen are these options:

[image]

I have two questions:

1. How can we give my google account permission to mess around with my own roles and permissions as well as the roles for the service accounts?
2. What is the current process for adding roles to a service account? Neither the docs nor the video from google seem to be up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Your second screenshot shows you attempting to grant roles *on* the service account (as a resource, i.e. who can access the service account). You're trying to give the service account the storage admin role on the project. To do that, go to the IAM page, click "add" then provide the service account's email address as the member and select the storage admin role.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain if this completely answers #1, but [Custom Roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles) (currently in alpha) will give you the ability to create roles with custom sets of permissions.  This will allow you to copy the Owner role and remove the billing permissions.

As for #2 - The screenshot shows the policy for the service account, not the project policy.  The policy for the service account determines who has permissions to use that service account, not what permissions the service account has.  You can find the project policy on the 'IAM & Admin > IAM' tab (instead of the IAM & Admin > Service accounts' tab).